# Why passing pointers to channel is slower

Tags: pointers, go, channel

I'm a newbie to golang, trying to rewrite my java server project in golang.

I found, passing pointers into channel cause almost 30% performance drop compared to passing values.

Here is a sample snippet:
    package main
    import (
        "time"
        "fmt"
    )

```
var c = make(chan t, 1024)
// var c = make(chan *t, 1024)
type t struct {
    a uint
    b uint
}

func main() {

    start := time.Now()
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        b := t{a:3, b:5}
        // c <- &b
        c <- b
    }
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println(t2)
}
```

## update. fix the package missing

Comment: How did you calculate? And ho define "performance drop"? I'm a little confused about the relation between the values 4000, 8000, and 30%.

Comment: The problem is not the performance of a channel, because it's the same, instead the question should be `Why is the performance impacted when I get a pointer from a local variable?` and Martin gave a good example about that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a value it can be stack allocated:

```
go run -gcflags '-m' tmp.go
# command-line-arguments
./tmp.go:18: inlining call to time.Time.Nanosecond
./tmp.go:24: inlining call to time.Time.Nanosecond
./tmp.go:25: t2 escapes to heap
./tmp.go:25: main ... argument does not escape
63613
```

As a pointer, it escapes to the heap:

```
go run -gcflags '-m' tmp.go
# command-line-arguments
./tmp.go:18: inlining call to time.Time.Nanosecond
./tmp.go:24: inlining call to time.Time.Nanosecond
./tmp.go:21: &b escapes to heap <-- Additional GC pressure
./tmp.go:20: moved to heap: b   <-- 
./tmp.go:25: t2 escapes to heap
./tmp.go:25: main ... argument does not escape
122513
```

Escaping to the heap introduces some overhead / GC pressure.

Looking at the assembly, the pointer version also introduces additional instructions, including:

```
go run -gcflags '-S' tmp.go
0x0055 00085 (...tmp.go:18) CALL    runtime.newobject(SB)
```

The non-pointer variant doesn't incur this overhead before calling `runtime.chansend1`.

Comment: Would you expect a 30% percent performance drop or a fixed value per passing operation?

Comment: In most cases no, but the above code is a contrived example where the heap allocations and additional assembly instructions are a large proportion of the programs' execution.

Comment: I'd expect the heap operations to be much more expansive then the referencing and dereferencing instructions, but since you have had the look into the code you maybe know better...

Comment: Good analysis, hope this answer will be the accepted one. And it shows some really interesting applications of the go tools *`go run -gcflags '-m'`* and *`go run -gcflags '-S`*

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement to the [good analysis of Martin Gallagher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41179423/2932052), it must be added that the way you are measuring is suspicious. The performance of such tiny programs varies a lot, so measuring should be done repeatedly. There are also some mistakes in your example.

First: it doesn't compile because the package statement is missing.

Second: there is an important difference between `Nanoseconds` and `Nanosecond`

I tried to evaluate your observation this way<sup>*</sup>:

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "fmt"
)

const (
    chan_size = 1000
    cycle_count = 1000
)

var (
    v_ch = make(chan t, chan_size)
    p_ch = make(chan *t, chan_size)
)

type t struct {
    a uint
    b uint
}

func fill_v() {
    for i := 0; i < chan_size; i++ {
        b := t{a:3, b:5}
        v_ch <- b
    }
}

func fill_p() {
    for i := 0; i < chan_size; i++ {
        b := t{a:3, b:5}
        p_ch <- &b
    }
}

func measure_f(f func()) int64 {
    start := time.Now()
    f();
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    return elapsed.Nanoseconds()
}

func main() {

    var v_nanos int64 = 0
    var p_nanos int64 = 0
    for i := 0; i<cycle_count; i++ {
        v_nanos += measure_f(fill_v);
        for i := 0; i < chan_size; i++ {
            _ = <- v_ch
        }
    }
    for i := 0; i<cycle_count; i++ {
        p_nanos += measure_f(fill_p);
        for i := 0; i < chan_size; i++ {
            _ = <- p_ch
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(
        "v:",v_nanos/cycle_count, 
        " p:", p_nanos/cycle_count, 
        "ratio (v/p):", float64(v_nanos)/float64(p_nanos))
}
```

There is indeed **a measurable performance drop** (I define drop like this `drop=1-(candidate/optimum)`), but although I repeat the code 1000 times, it varies between 25% and 50%, I'm not even sure how the heap is recycled and when, so it maybe **hard to quantify** at all.

---

<sup>*</sup>see a "running" demo on [ideone](https://ideone.com/vzIiTK)

...note that stdout is frozen: `v: 34875  p: 59420 ratio (v/p)0.586923845267128`

For some reason, it was not possible to run [this code in the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U8DdLr2kpB)

Comment: Regarding Go Playground issues; that's because `time.Now()` always returns `2009-11-10 23:00:00 +0000 UTC`

Comment: @MartinGallagher On the Go Playground time always starts at `2009-11-10 23:00:00`, but the time is not frozen, if you call `time.Now()` at a later time, it returns a different value: [time test](https://play.golang.org/p/pvk_vw5Hfm).

Comment: @icza maybe you need to sleep for that? My performance test obviously absolutely consumed no time in Go. But in reality it does, you wait longer with bigger values for `chan_size` or `cycle_count`

Comment: @icza; sorry I forgot to add context: https://play.golang.org/p/yi_2L6g0C3

Comment: @MartinGallagher Yes, the Playground uses "fake timing". It doesn't advance by itself, and sleeps are just simulated by "jumps" in time. You can read more about it here: [**Inside the Go Playground: Faking time**](https://blog.golang.org/playground#TOC_3.1.)